# Writing into csv with php problems

Tags: php, csv, file

I have a problem. I'm trying to get some data from a database into a .csv table.

```
$fn=fopen($path.$filename, "w");

$addstring = file_get_contents($path.$filename);

$addstring = 'Azonosito;Datum;Ido;Leiras;IP-cim;allomasnév;MAC-cim;Felhasznalonev;Tranzakcioazonosito;Lekerdezes eredmenye;Vizsgalat ideje;Korrelacios azonosito;DHCID;';
/*$addstring .= "\n";*/

$sql="select * from dhcpertekeles.dhcpk";
$result =mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {

    $addstring .= "\n".$row[0].";".$row[1].";".$row[2].";".$row[3].";".$row[4].";".$row[5].";".$row[6].";".$row[7].";".$row[8].";".$row[9].";".$row[10].";".$row[11].";".$row[12].";";

 };
};

    /*file_put_contents($path.$filename, $addstring);*/

    fwrite($fn, $addstring);
    fclose($fn);
```

The data is in the following format:
The first addstring contains the column names, and has no issues

the second (addstring .=) contains the data:
ID($row[0]), Date($row[1]), Time($row[2]), Description($row[3]), IP($row[4]), Computer name($row[5]), MAC($row[6]), User($row[7])(empty), Transactionid($row[8]), query result($row[9]), query time($row[10]), correlation id($row[11])(empty), DHCID($row[12])(empty)

It is basically daily DHCP server data, uploaded to a database. Now, the code works, it does write everything i want to the csv, but there are 2 problems.

1, the code for some inexplicable reason, inserts an empty row into the csv table between the rows that contain the data. Removing $row[12] fixes this. I tried removing special characters, converting spaces into something that can be seen, and even converting empty string into something that can be seen. Yet nothing actually worked, i even tried file_puts_content(same for the second problem) instead of fwrite, but nothing. The same thing keeps happening. If i remove \n it will work, but the 2nd row onwards will be misplaced to the right by 1 column.

2, For some reason, the last 2 character is removed from the csv. The string that is to be inserted into the csv still contains said 2 characters before writing it to the file. Tried both fwrite and file_puts_content.

As for the .csv format, the data clumns are divided by ; and rows by \n.

Also tried reading the file with both libre office and excel thinking it might be excel that was splurging but no.

Comment: better use fputcsv while writing to csv. it is recommended way and will take care of some dirty work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fputcsv()` function. I didn't test following code but I think it should work.

```
$file = fopen($path . $filename, 'w');

$header = array(
    'Azonosito', 
    'Datum', 
    'Ido', 
    'Leiras', 
    'IP-cim', 
    'allomasnév', 
    'MAC-cim', 
    'Felhasznalonev', 
    'Tranzakcioazonosito', 
    'Lekerdezes eredmenye', 
    'Vizsgalat ideje', 
    'Korrelacios azonosito', 
    'DHCID'
);

fputcsv($file, $header, ';');

$sql = "select * from dhcpertekeles.dhcpk";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        fputcsv($file, $row, ';');
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thank you! both your solution and the person's below worked. I was having a headache over this. Now, the empty row is gone, but i'm still missing 2 characters that are in the string up until the write command is issued. Also, my database is in utf-8, the file in utf-8 without bom and the code is utf-8 as well as defined in the header.

Answer (score 0):

The `$addstring = file_get_contents($path.$filename)` doesn't does nothing because you're overwriting that variable in the next line.

To remove the extra row on 12 did you tried removing the \n **AND** the \r with something like:

`$row[12] = strtr($row[12], array("\n"=>'', "\r"=>''))`;

You can also check which ascii characters are you receiving in the $row[12] with this function taken form the php site:

```
function AsciiToInt($char){
$success = "";
    if(strlen($char) == 1)
        return "char(".ord($char).")";
    else{
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($char); $i++){
            if($i == strlen($char) - 1)
                $success = $success.ord($char[$i]);
            else
                $success = $success.ord($char[$i]).",";
        }
        return "char(".$success.")";
    }
}
```

Another tip can be the database it's returning UTF-8 or UTF-16 and you're losing some characters in the text file.

Try looking at that with the `mb_detect_encoding` function.

Comment: Thank you! both your solution and the person's above worked, also my database is indeed in utf-8, the file is in utf-8 without bom and the code is also using utf-8 as defined in the header. Can you tell me more about how this can lead to character loss as i'm still missing the 2 characters at the end? thanks.

Comment: The other code fixed your line breaks in field 12 ? Check the field 12 with the AsciiToInt function I posted to see which special characters it has. Test also opening the CSV file with one UTF-8 editor like Notepad++ to see if the characters appear or not. And tell us how do you know you lack two characters in the file. Hoy you count the characters? Mind that \r and \n count as character.

Comment: I can see the missing characters as i manually filled in all fields each field i gave a number and the last field is missing the whole double digit number, as for how i know its 2 characters, it's because at first i added the \n character after row[12] and then from the number 12 1 was still there but the 2 disappeared after i removed the \n character, the whole number 12 disappeared. Also i printed the whole string before writing it to the file and it had the characters, but once they are in the csv they're missing. Checked the csv with np++ this is what i get:

Comment: 0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;
I'll check your function in a min.

Comment: Ok, i checked out that code, for row[0] it returns things like char(51,48) char(49,49) char(51,50) etc, but for row[12] it's all char() except the last one which is char missing the () from the end lol. printing the thing still gives char() for the last row[12].

Comment: char() means it's empty. As you said you added the \n to the field 12, but with strtr you removed they so that's why it's empty now. The numbers you see are the ascii code of each character. char(51,48) = 30 You can see in one Ascii Table what means each number. There are some characters which are control characters like (tab (9), space (32), return line (13), carriage return (10), and so on which are not visible and that characters can be the ones you don't have on the csv file. http://www.asciitable.com/